# Installation of OpenCV in anaconda not showing up in VS Code in Windows 10

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I have a VM running only Anaconda.  There are no other available installations of Python.  This is all I see when I run "Apps and Features" in Windows 10 and filter for Python (note that it is Python 3.7.4):

[image]

When I go to the Conda prompt and enter conda list, I see that I have openCV installed :

[image]

but it's with a version of Python 3.7.6:

[image]

However when I open VS Code and I set my Python Path to the version in the Anaconda folder: (C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\Python.exe) and try to import OpenCV, I get the "module not found" error.  When I create a new python file and run

```
help("modules")
```

I do not see OpenCV in the list below in the terminal even though its installed.

[image]

Any idea how this is happening?  I just don't see a second installation of Python on my PC, but why am I seeing 3.7.4 and 3.7.6 and is this possibly causing my issue?

Edit:  Added a picture of the error I get when trying to run it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install anaconda plugin in VSCode and select your conda environment in the bottom left of VSCode window.

If you didn't create a conda environment, the you will probably have installed the package in the base environment.

Edit: Reading the [PyPi project](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), I found the right way to import opencv in python code.

```
import cv2
```

Comment: Install anaconda plugin is installed.  I am selecting the "Python 3.7.6 64-bit ('base': conda).  It's like VS code doesn't see the OpenCV I installed through Conda list.  I can only see i have OpenCV installed in conda list, won't show up in pip list or VS Code when I do a "help("modules")".  Is there something I'm missing with get conda install packages to work in VS Code?

Comment: Try to remove the python path variable. It's not necessary.

Comment: I think it's about how you are running the python script, not the installed package. What are you doing to run it?

Comment: You mean the one in settings?  I did that but it didn't make a difference.  I thought Anaconda was supposed to make this easier?  I did a pip install from inside Anaconda Prompt to try it that way but I still can't get VS Code to see it.  The only environment I have is the 3.7.6 I mentioned above

Comment: 1) Opened VS code from Anaconda Prompt using "code".  2) Environment set to Python 3.7.6 64-bit ('base': conda).  3) Create a new file. 4) type "import opencv"  5) Get the Python Module Not Found error

Comment: Note that opencv works fine in Jupyter Notebook, which I don't care to use either except to show results.  Hard to debug in there.

Comment: After typing "import opencv", you have to do something to get this error message. It don't show up when you just write the last "v" on the import. I want to know this.

Comment: Just created a python file in VS Code that has only one line which is the import opencv.  I click on the green box at the top and it runs in the terminal and gives me that error

Comment: My goodness I am dumb.  I had the wrong import statement.  I guess one positive is I spent the last few hours learning about how these environments work.  I originally thought the base wasn't working because when I did "conda list" it only had two packages.  Created a new environment, activated it, and still had the issue.  Then saw your import cv2 and suddenly it worked - Thanks for your patience.

Comment: _If you didn't create a conda environment, the you will probably want to choose the base environment._ That's a bad idea, if they didn't create an environment, then they should.

Comment: @Vaslo Do not use the base environment, create a new one.

Comment: Yes. Nice comment AMC. I mean Vaslo probably installed the package on the base environment, not he should use it. My bad. It's better pratice learn about environments and create new environments to work.

Comment: Thank you both.  I learned that as well through this process.